# Retrieving a specific row from a CSV file based on input

Tags: python

At the moment I have a program which retrieves all of the information from the CSV file and outputs it like so:

```
['USER', 'PASS', 'INFO']
['example', 'pass', 'Apple']
['example1', 'pass1', 'Banana']
['example2', 'pass2', 'Strawberry']
```

With the code I'm using being:

```
import csv

username = input("Username... ")

with open('data.csv', 'rt') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

What I'd like to do is check the user input against the usernames listed in the CSV file and if matches, print the corresponding INFO value. So if the username variable was example1, Banana would be printed. Is there any way of doing this, similar to MySQL etc.?

Much appreciated!

Comment: If the table is unsorted and you only search one username simply add an `if row[0] == username:`

Comment: @Nabla - love your nickname :)) But yes, if the CSV is small enough might as well load it into memory. Or go line by line as Nabla suggests.

Comment: Aside: since it seems like you're using Python 3, you should `newline=''` when opening files to pass to the csv reader, as in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to match only once, just loop through the CSV file and test each row:

```
with open('data.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == username:
            print(row)
```

If you need to refer to the different usernames in your code more often, and the CSV is not huge use a dictionary:

```
with open('data.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    usernames = {r[0]: r for r in reader}

print usernames[username]
```